# Visual Studio/IIS Express won't create localDB MDF file with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working with an ASP NET MVC 5 app, which is making use of a code-first Entity Framework approach to the database.

This is the connection string I'm using

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Projects\myProject\trunk\website\App_Data\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My website actually loads fine as on startup, and at the index page, there are no calls to the database. However, as soon as I make an API call to interact with the database, I get the following error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

The folder structure definitely exists, I've double checked this many times, the only thing that is missing is the file I define, but I believe this part is meant to be created for me.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to create just an empty local database? Entities will create the schema structure, but I doubt it creates the local db file.

Comment: Are you getting this error while running in debug / through VS or under IIS? If the later, does the account IIS is running under have access to the path of the mdf?

Comment: try running as admin see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Gusman I've had this working in other projects before, though, without ever creating an empty DB :/ krilovich I am running as admin at the moment.

Comment: Can you try it with "default" connection string: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True` (what I mean is using v11.0 as localDb instance and |DataDirectory| instead of full path)?